# Convert Strings to Floats and sum them up

Tags: java, kotlin, sum

I have a function:

```
fun sumUpStrings(strings: List<String>) = strings.map { it.toFloat() }.sum()
```

and a test:

```
@Test
fun testSumUpStrings() {
    val strings = listOf(
        "12.2", "7.0", "33.33"
    )

    val result = mapper.sumUpStrings(strings)

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(12.2 + 7.0 + 33.33)
}
```

The output of the test is:

> expected:<52.53[]> but was:<52.53[0003f]> Expected :52.53[] Actual
> :52.53[0003f]

I was expecting the test to succeed. Can someone explain this phenomenon to me?

Comment: expecting an exact result is not advised with floats
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: @Raildex it does, thanks!